# How can I "play" a sound from its PCM data in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, audio, client-server, audio-streaming, getusermedia

I'm building a videochat application. I used "getUserMedia" to get access to the microphone. I get and send the PCM data to the server with the following code:

```js
 var bufferSize = 4096;

 audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext || window.mozAudioContext)(); //Crear conteto de audio
 volume = audioContext.createGain();
 audioInput = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource( e );
 audioInput.connect( volume );
 processor = audioContext.createScriptProcessor( bufferSize, 1, 1 );

 processor.onaudioprocess = function ( e ){

 if( e === undefined ) return;

  var left = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData( 0 );

  if( (left.buffer instanceof ArrayBuffer) && (left.length > 0) && (left.buffer !== undefined) && (left[0] != 0)){
   if( ws ){
    if( ws.readyState == WebSocket.OPEN ){
     ws.send( left.buffer );
    }//Fin if
   }//Fin ws
  }//Fin if

 }//Fin function

 volume.connect( processor );
 processor.connect( audioContext.destination );
```

It works perfectly. But, I cannot play the audio received on the server. The client sends to the server a Float32Array containing the PCM audio-data captured from the local microphone. This is my code to play the audio when the server receives the PCM data:

```js
function PlayAudio( param ){

 // creates the audio context
    var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
    
 // Create an empty two second stereo buffer at the
 // sample rate of the AudioContext
 var frameCount = audioCtx.sampleRate * 2.0;
 var bufferSize = 4096;

 var myArrayBuffer = audioCtx.createBuffer( 1, bufferSize, audioCtx.sampleRate);

 var nowBuffering = myArrayBuffer.getChannelData(0);

    for (var i = 0 , len = param.length ; i < len ; i++) {
     nowBuffering[i] = param[i];
    }//fin for

    //create a buffer source to play the audio
   var source = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
  
   //Copy the buffer
   source.buffer = myArrayBuffer;

   //Connect the audio input
   source.connect(audioCtx.destination);

   //Start playing
   source.start();

}
```

I'm testing the server with only one client. The server only "echoes" the PCM data received from the client. The PCM data is sent and received correctly. When I play the audio, I just hear "noise" instead of my recorded voice.

I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advances for any help.

Comment: did you find the solution?